# Is there way to attach VS 2015 debugger to existing process running on Windows Phone 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Is there way to attach VS 2015 debugger to existing process running on Windows Phone 10?

The process is built in debug mode but is not running in debugger.

Comment: The only way you can use debug version on device is by connecting that device to your system and selecting **Device** in debug option and deploying it in debug version.<br/>
Once its deployed you can find all your predefined breakpoints being hit as per required. But if you disconnect the device in between then connection is lost and you wont be able to receive data unless you are Using third party crash report or generating logs in the local dump.

Comment: I do not disconnect the device. I deploy debug version of the app, run the app without debugger and at some point I want to attach the debugger to the running process.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your statement run the app without debugger? how are you doing that?

Comment: You deploy the app to the phone from VS 2015. You run the app on the phone.

Comment: Yes and by disconnection I meant you do not stop the deployment, by clicking on stop. Are you doing that? Since if you do that then your deployment session gets over